# scrbook: remove margin notes for index entries

Tags: koma-script, indexing, marginpar

I'm using the `scrbook` class. I don't like the way that my index entries are included as margin notes. How can I prevent the index entries from being shown in the margins? I consulted the KOMA-Script manual but was unable to find anything that addresses this issue.

Sample code follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openright,12pt,chapterprefix=true,index=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx,showidx}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\date{}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{The Chapter Name}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{The Chapter Name}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\index{Lorem ipsum!dolor sit amet}
Sed a tellus augue. Phasellus ut ultrices velit.
\index{Sed a tellus!augue}
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It is the `\usepackage{showidx}` that is placing the index entries in the margin, not the `scrbook` class.  So removing the `showidx` from the list of packages will remove the margin notes for index enteries.

Comment: This solved the problem--newbie mistake. Thanks! However I don't see an option to accept this answer.

Comment: Have posted it as an answer, you should now see the up arrow for voting and check mark for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

It is the `\usepackage{showidx}` that is placing the index entries in the margin, *not* the `scrbook` class. So removing the `showidx` from the list of packages will remove the margin notes for index entries.